# How can I add a Trace() to every method call in C#?

Tags: c#, logging, trace

I am having a hard time tracking down a lock issue, so I would like to log every method call's entry and exit. I've done this before with C++ without having to add code to every method. Is this possible with C#?

Comment: Given that you know what you are locking and roughly where it is, how about posting some code...

Comment: Be warned, doing this will most likely change the timing of your app significantly enough that your locking issue disappears.

Comment: Changing the environment your code is failing in by automatically adding additional function calls might modify the state to the point where the dead lock no longer occurs.  Posting code might be best to try to solve the problem.

Comment: Very true - even hooking a debugger to the application while it's running prevents the issue from occurring. I didn't end up going this route, I found the cause using WinDbg and dozens of stacktrace dumps.

Comment: Just for the record, I didn't end up going this way. I ended up solving the problem using WinDbg and dozens of stacktrace dumps.

Comment: I am facing the same issue but with C++ and I don't want to add code to every method. Could you please point me in the right direction. I am not trying to debug the application. I want to use this call entry/exit log for some other analysis.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Probably your best bet would be to use an AOP (aspect oriented programming) framework to automatically call tracing code before and after a method execution. A popular choice for AOP and .NET is [PostSharp](http://www.postsharp.net/).

Comment: Thanks - PostSharp even comes with an example project that does something similar. :)

Comment: Recently postsharp diagnostics toolkit has been introduced http://www.sharpcrafters.com/blog/post/Configuring-PostSharp-Diagnostics-Toolkits.aspx

Answer (score 6):

If your primary goal is to log function entry/exit points and occasional information in between, I've had good results with an **Disposable** logging object where the ***constructor traces the function entry***, and ***Dispose() traces the exit***. This allows calling code to simply wrap each method's code inside a single **using** statement.  Methods are also provided for arbitrary logs in between.  Here is a complete C# ETW event tracing class along with a function entry/exit wrapper:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Diagnostics.Tracing;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace MyExample
{
    // This class traces function entry/exit
    // Constructor is used to automatically log function entry.
    // Dispose is used to automatically log function exit.
    // use "using(FnTraceWrap x = new FnTraceWrap()){ function code }" pattern for function entry/exit tracing
    public class FnTraceWrap : IDisposable
    {
        string methodName;
        string className;

        private bool _disposed = false;

        public FnTraceWrap()
        {
            StackFrame frame;
            MethodBase method;

            frame = new StackFrame(1);
            method = frame.GetMethod();
            this.methodName = method.Name;
            this.className = method.DeclaringType.Name;

            MyEventSourceClass.Log.TraceEnter(this.className, this.methodName);
        }

        public void TraceMessage(string format, params object[] args)
        {
            string message = String.Format(format, args);
            MyEventSourceClass.Log.TraceMessage(message);
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (!this._disposed)
            {
                this._disposed = true;
                MyEventSourceClass.Log.TraceExit(this.className, this.methodName);
            }
        }
    }

    [EventSource(Name = "MyEventSource")]
    sealed class MyEventSourceClass : EventSource
    {
        // Global singleton instance
        public static MyEventSourceClass Log = new MyEventSourceClass();

        private MyEventSourceClass()
        {
        }

        [Event(1, Opcode = EventOpcode.Info, Level = EventLevel.Informational)]
        public void TraceMessage(string message)
        {
            WriteEvent(1, message);
        }

        [Event(2, Message = "{0}({1}) - {2}: {3}", Opcode = EventOpcode.Info, Level = EventLevel.Informational)]
        public void TraceCodeLine([CallerFilePath] string filePath = "",
                                  [CallerLineNumber] int line = 0,
                                  [CallerMemberName] string memberName = "", string message = "")
        {
            WriteEvent(2, filePath, line, memberName, message);
        }

        // Function-level entry and exit tracing
        [Event(3, Message = "Entering {0}.{1}", Opcode = EventOpcode.Start, Level = EventLevel.Informational)]
        public void TraceEnter(string className, string methodName)
        {
            WriteEvent(3, className, methodName);
        }

        [Event(4, Message = "Exiting {0}.{1}", Opcode = EventOpcode.Stop, Level = EventLevel.Informational)]
        public void TraceExit(string className, string methodName)
        {
            WriteEvent(4, className, methodName);
        }
    }
}
```

Code that uses it will look something like this:

```
public void DoWork(string foo)
{
    using (FnTraceWrap fnTrace = new FnTraceWrap())
    {
        fnTrace.TraceMessage("Doing work on {0}.", foo);
        /*
        code ...
        */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A profiler is great for looking at your running code during development but if you're looking for the ability to do custom traces in production, then, as Denis G. mentionned, [PostSharp](http://www.postsharp.org/) is the perfect tool: you don't have to change all your code and you can easily switch it on/off.

It's also easy to set-up in a few minutes and Gaël Fraiteur, the creator of PostSharp even has videos that shows you how easy it is to add tracing to an existing app.
You will find examples and tutorials in the [documentation section](http://www.postsharp.org/documentation).

Answer (score 2):

Use [ANTS Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/Products/ants_profiler/index.htm) from Red Gate would be your best bet.  Failing that, look into [interceptors](http://www.castleproject.org/container/documentation/trunk/usersguide/interceptors.html) in [Castle Windsor](http://www.castleproject.org/container/index.html).  That does assume you're loading your types via IoC though.

Reflection is another way, you can use the [System.Reflection.Emit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.aspx) methods to "write" code into memory.  That code could replace your method's code, and execute it but with appropriate logging.  Good luck on that one, though...  Easier would be to use an Aspect Oriented Programming framework like [Aspect#](http://www.castleproject.org/aspectsharp/index.html).

Comment: ANTS is great (as is the VS built in profiler), but the drawback is you might change the memory/timing 'footprint' of the app. and possibly not experience the lock...

Comment: Tracing would also change the timing.

Comment: Yes, it's Heisenberg's Uncertainty Principle.  By observing the experiment you may well change the results of the experiment. That's thread sync debugging for you...

Answer (score 1):

It might be waiting for the lock issue to take hold, doing a memory dump and analysing the call stack on various threads. You can use [DebugDiag](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=28bd5941-c458-46f1-b24d-f60151d875a3&displaylang=en) or the adplus script (hang mode, in this case) that comes with [Debugging Tools for Windows](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/debugging/default.mspx).

[Tess Ferrandez](http://blogs.msdn.com/tess/) also has an [excellent lab series](http://blogs.msdn.com/tess/pages/net-debugging-demos-information-and-setup-instructions.aspx) on learning to debug various issues using .NET memory dumps. I highly recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

How do you know that it's happening? If this is a multithreaded application, i would recommend testing for the condition and calling System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break() at runtime when it's detected. Then, simply open up the Threads window and step through the call stacks on each relevant thread.