# Is it possible to programmatically set trace points in VS 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

This is in reference to the Visual Studio automation interface. It is possible to set breakpoints in a program using the method:

```
EnvDTE.Debugger.Breakpoints.Add(...)
```

However, I don't think it's possible to configure trace points this way. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the answers in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/791930/how-to-programatically-add-a-tracepoint-for-visual-studio) particularly the [BreakWhenHit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte80.breakpoint2.breakwhenhit.aspx) = false, [Message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte80.breakpoint2.message.aspx), and [Macro](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte80.breakpoint2.macro.aspx) properties of the [Breakpoint2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte80.breakpoint2.aspx) interface.

Comment: Not sure how I missed that! Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

Or you could also look at a logging framework like Log4Net.

Comment: Cheers, but I'm looking at a more dynamic way of debugging running code.