# How-to log execution order of a C# application

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I add a Trace() to every method call in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/559148/how-can-i-add-a-trace-to-every-method-call-in-c)

Is there an easy way to log all called functions (in order of execution, also passed argument values to these f-ns) in a C# application while it is being executed in debug mode in VS2010? For example, I press some button on my form, some complex code is invoked. Now I want to see what functions in what classes with what arguments.

Note that adding debug/trace info to functions is not an option!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IntelliTrace in VS2010

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264915.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee336126.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need an AOP logger, like Log4Net. Instead of putting in Debug/Trace writes, you decorate the methods you want logged with attributes; the attributes will fire events when the method is entered and exited, which the logger will respond to, writing the text you specify for those events to the log file. I believe you can also specify global rules for logging so you don't even have to decorate each method.

Comment: One of the AOP logger Keith referring to is PostSharp. http://www.sharpcrafters.com/